# Adding file as header in source-source transformation using clang

Tags: c++, clang, code-translation

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  workFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

I have a sample code as above, but the function being called in 'main' is in another header file 'header.h'. So after the transformation, the code must look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
int main(void) {
  workFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

Please help. I am using clang, c++ coding and the transformation code available in this [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just call it along the same way you call header files to your program and it should work.

Comment: I have not called any header files in my program. When I do the transformation, <stdio.h> is directly added to the newly obtained file. And I do not want 'header.h' to be in the old file. I just want it to be in the new file.

Comment: You mean using <> instead of the " "?

Comment: Correct. Can you please explain what you are saying with an example ? I am very new to clang.

Comment: Whenever you create your own header classes, using " " is the standard for header files. Using <> is more used for sections of standard C++ code that are defaulted within the compiler itself.